# How to get the feed from a Shockwave Flash live stream

Tags: flash, camera, port, http-live-streaming

I have cameras that send streams to an online video player UI (which is made with Flash and so requires using *Flash Player* browser plugin). Unfortunately, it gives no official way to access the cameras outside the UI.

Using Google Chrome network tools as well as "Grab Any Media" I found RTMP.swf?v=xxx. Unfortunately, this seems to be a trick, when I go to the URL I am shown the loading image (The UI shows the icon at the end of that URL for about 2 seconds, then shows the feed).

All I really need is a way to get the JPG feed for my local UI I am creating, how can I go about this?

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to get images/video from local camera in the flash app on the same machine?

Comment: The video feed has a `rtmp://` URL? You can't use Adobe's RTMP format within HTML5 live streams (since HTML5 only support HLS or DASH formats). Remember `.swf` is the Flash app, it is loaded into browser page by your installed _Flash Player_ plugin)... _"for my local UI I am creating"_ is it made with ActionScript code (Flash)? Otherwise it may not be possible. If using C# or Java or Android languages you could search online for a library that will do "handshake" with RTMP server to receive stream.